# OOP - creating class adding to list then deleting

Tags: python

I have to create a program that will ask user to input details of a student including their ID number (which is to be saved to a global list). Then the user will be returned to the main menu where they are asked to view add or delete.

I can do the adding a student, I have done view , I have created the class etc... but I cannot get it to delete. We have to delete a student we have added by entering their ID number and then after deletion the program must confirm who it has deleted.

```
def removeStudent():
    std_delete = raw_input("Please enter Students ID number to remove: ")
    for std in students:
        if std.studentID == std_delete:
            print "Student ID",std_delete,"has been deleted" % std.studentID
            students.remove(std)
            break
```

Comment: What specifically about deleting a student are you having problems with? (Does the problem require you paste your code in its entirety?)

Comment: Please no setter and getter methods. You're programming Python and not Java.

Comment: well i posted it because I didn't know what would need to be seen, like I said I'm new to python. I have no idea how to delete a student from my global list once they have been added, this is what I need to do.

Comment: I understand you say not get and set etc but like i said... This is the way we are being shown

Comment: Who showed you this? You should go and slap your bad tutor.

Comment: **The kindergarten here behaviour stops right now.**

Comment: You really need to point your instructor to http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/. Also read it on your own; search for "accessors" to find out why you shouldn't use getter/setter methods in python.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gna have a read because I've noticed a lot of people saying not to use getter/setter methods but our tutor is saying that's the way we have to do it... most confusing! =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confuse how to delete a student instance

```
std_delete = raw_input("Student To Delete")
for std in students:
    if std.studentID == std_delete:
        print "Student ID %d has been deleted " % std.studentID
        students.remove(std)
        break
```

or you may using filter function

```
std_delete = raw_input("Student To Delete")
students = filter(lambda x: x.studentID != std_delete, students)
```

Comment: i'm tryong this and it keeps coming up with error saying: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Rusowicz/Desktop/python classes.py", line 112, in <module>
    removeStudent()
  File "/Users/Rusowicz/Desktop/python classes.py", line 95, in removeStudent
    if std.id == std_delete:
AttributeError: Student instance has no attribute 'id'

Comment: in this case , you just need use `std.studentID`

Comment: OMG thank you! the only person that just helped and didn't whinge about me putting too much code or something else! Thanks!!! =D

Answer (score 0):

This must be the code you are looking for.

```
def delete_student(id):
    for student in students:
        if student.studentID == id:
           index = students.index(student)
           break
    print "Deleted student %s" % students.pop(index)
```